# brew install package asks to install command line tools from a path that doesn't exist

Tags: command-line, xcode, homebrew

I messed up my command line tools. I already had them installed (and were working pretty great), I also installed the beta 2 macOS 10 version from the apple developers site because the command `brew install putty` was asking me to either remove Xcode or upgrade it. (Here is where I messed up, instead of installing an upgraded version of Xcode.app, I installed Xcode command line tools 10.14)

So now the command `brew install putty` gives the error

```
Error: Your Xcode (9.4.1) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 10.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

when I run `xcode-select --install` it says the command line tools are already installed.

If I remove Xcode.app it shows that:

```
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the stan
dalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
Error: Git must be installed and in your PATH!
xcrun: error: active developer path ("/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer") does not exist
Use `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the stan
dalone command line developer tools.
See `man xcode-select` for more details.
Error: The Command Line Tools header package must be installed on Mojave.
The installer is located at:
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Packages/macOS_SDK_headers_for_macOS_10.14.pkg
```

and the path mentioned in the above errors for the `pkg` file for me to install doesn't exist

Comment: Which version of Xcode is currently installed? Did you run the command line tool installer after installing Xcode 10.0?

Comment: @nohillside I ran another installer after that too for a previous version. Xcode 10.0 is not installed. But thew Xcode command line tools beta 2 for that were installed once

Comment: Why don‘t you just install Xcode 10 then and proceed?